# Memcpy: wrong number of bytes

Tags: c, memcpy

I have a variable size matrix that I need to back-up at every iteration. For this, I use a pointer of the same size (in bytes) and the memcpy function.

```
void DoSmth(int ** mainMat, ...){ 
   int * backUp = malloc(columns * lines * sizeof(int));
   ...
   memcpy(backUp, mainMat, columns * lines * sizeof(int)); // back-up
   ...
   memcpy(mainMat, backUp, columns * lines * sizeof(int)); // restore
   ...
}
```

The program compiles and runs without error, but I noticed the data I backed-up and restored is incomplete, more exactly only the first n lines of the matrix are correct, **the last lines aren`t restored**. If I increase the third parameter of memcpy ( for example, instead of 400 - 10 * 10 * sizeof(int) - i tried with 600), all lines of the matrix are restored.

My question is why this happens and how can I solve it.

Comment: Can you please provide some code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: `memcpy(backUp, *mainMat, columns * lines * sizeof(int));`, `memcpy(*mainMat, backup, columns * lines * sizeof(int));`

Comment: @MayankJain I cannot provide more code, sorry. But all the info is in the pseudocode.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY your solution only reduced the number of lines that are not restored,  the last lines of the matrix are still wrong.

Comment: I guessed that because there is no information about other parts. If these corrections are wrong, more information is needed.

Comment: all the data that `int** mainMat` points to isn't necessarily contiguous in memory .. if it is you just got "lucky" and you can't rely on that. You'll need to individually back up the data that each `int*` points to individually ... if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @yano i work with some really big matrix and for loops have a bigger time complexity. If it isn`t contiguous, why it works if I force the size of bytes to be copied?

Comment: Im imagining that `mainMat` was allocated something like `mainMat = malloc(columns*sizeof int*); for (int i=0; i<columns; i++){ mainMat[i] = malloc(lines*sizeof int); }`. If my imagination is wrong thatd be useful info to add to the question.

Comment: @yano: you are right, thank you. Copied line by line and it worked. I was sure about the correctness of that memcpy because I saw it in another response to a similar question.

Comment: good deal, glad to hear it! If you have a 2D array, `int mainMat[lines][columns];`, then that will be contiguous in memory and you could `memcpy` the entire thing somewhere else, but with dynamically allocated memory you cannot assume that successive calls to `malloc` will give you contiguous blocks... in fact they probably wont.

Comment: I will try inspecting with gdb for a better understanding. Couldn`t use static arrays, the matrix was too big for the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
memcpy(backUp, mainMat, columns * lines * sizeof(int));
```

You are calling `memcpy` as though `mainMat` points at or into an array of arrays.  But this is not possible, since `mainMat` is a pointer to pointer.  It probably points into an array of pointers into arrays, instead.  Since an array is NOT a pointer, these two types are not compatible.

In fact, your `memcpy` isn't necessarily copying the `int` objects at all: it is copying the bytes of some `int*` pointers into and out of the allocated memory.

If you need to copy all the `int` objects out of and into the storage associated with `mainMat`, you will need to loop over the elements of `mainMat` and copy out of and into each pointer it contains.  This will copy one row or one column at a time (depending on your matrix orientation convention).

Comment: Thank you and @yano. I copied line-by-line and it works.